# Finding the only odd number or the only even number in a list

Tags: python

I am looking at this challenge:

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

Here is my attempt:

```
def find_outlier(i):
    p=0
    im=0
    if i[0]%2==0 :
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if i[0]%2==0 :
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if i[0]%2==0 :
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if p<im :
        for e in i :
            if e%2 ==0:
                return print(e)
    else:
        for e in i :
            if e%2 !=0 :
                return  print(e)        
find_outlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21])
```

It returns 3 when it should clearly return 160.

What am I missing?

Comment: Unclear as to what you're asking. And your code is formatted wrong. Could we have a screenshot of the terminal output?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code does not make sense, which makes it hard to pinpoint a specific problem. Perhaps you could write it more clearly.

Comment: ``"it returns 3"`` - nope, no matter what, that function will always return ``None`` (though it may *print* 3).

Comment: Your three `if` statements are all identical.  They're all looking at the first element.  You want `i[1]` in the second and `i[2]` in the third.

Comment: Also I suggest using easy to understand variables, especially if you want to post a question on it. It's very simple code but looks very ummm ill just say hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: You got several answers. Any feed-back?

Answer (score 1):

Your three if statements are all identical. They're all looking at the first element. You want `i[1]` in the second and `i[2]` in the third.  That solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- The code looks three times at the first element of the list, while you should look at three *different* elements
- The `return` statements return the value that the `print` function returns, which is `None`. You move the printing outside of the function, as the function should just *return* the number, not print it.

So if we only correct these two issues we get:

```
def find_outlier(i):
    p=0
    im=0
    if i[0]%2==0 :
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if i[1]%2==0 :  # element at 1
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if i[2]%2==0 :  # element at 2
        p=p+1
    else :
        im=im+1
    if p<im :
        for e in i :
            if e%2 ==0:
                return e  # return the value, not `print()`
    else:
        for e in i :
            if e%2 !=0 :
                return e

print(find_outlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]))
```

Now you can also avoid code repetition:

- The variables `p` and `im` will always add up to 3, so one of those can be left out. You have all the info you need when you just track the value of `im` only.
- The three `if` blocks are essentially the same, so a loop that iterates 3 times is more appropriate. You can even use `sum()`.
- The final `if..else` blocks also look very similar. You can instead determine what `e%2` should be equal to (with a variable) and just keep one block. Also this can be done with a shorter expression, using `next()`.

I would also suggest using more descriptive variable names:

```
def find_outlier(lst):
    odds = sum(value%2 for value in lst[:3])
    target = int(odds < 2)
    return next(value for value in lst if value%2==target)

print(find_outlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the repeated statements will append your p and im and not give you the values you expect from them.

There are many ways to approach this task, but this could be a good beginner-friendly approach to reference:

```
def find_outlier(array):
    evens = []  # this will be filled with the evens numbers
    odds = []. # this will be filled with the odds numbers

    for val in array:
        if val % 2 == 0:  # if even, add to evens
            evens.append(val)
        else:  # If not even (i.e. odd) add to odds
            odds.append(val)

    if len(evens_index) == 1:  # outlier will have a list length 1
        return evens[0]
    elif len(odds_index) == 1:
        return odds[0]
    else:
        return None.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an outlier you want to check i[0] i[1] and i[2]. You are checking i[0] 3 times.

Since p is 3 and im is 0, it thinks it's looking for the first odd number it comes across, which is 3.